# Is it possible to build a conveyor network from an XML file in Anylogic?

Tags: xml, configuration, anylogic, parameterized

Is it possible to build a conveyor network from an XML file using the Anylogic material handling library?

I have been looking for a way to show that a conveyor system can behave exactly the same even after reconfiguration is done. Suppose the original model is built for reconfiguration using parameters. These parameters can be reconfigured by using an XML file. I would be happy to hear any response on this scenario - is it possible to build this in Anylogic?

Comment: With "reconfiguration using parameters", do you mean the parameters like speed, acceleration, deceleration ? Or do you mean you want to compare different layouts? In the first case, you can just load the XML with the Text File module and then parse the XML using an available external Java XML library. Finally you can use set_myParameter() functions to update the values during runtime, or you directly set them at the start screen before experiment start. The latter case, building a conveyor layout from XML, is also possible, but requires code to create the conveyors during runtime.

Comment: Thank you @Florian. The second case fits what I meant with reconfiguration. Is there any online source related to this kind of problem? I couldn't find any.